# Rendering Parameters on EXM missing in CE tree

Tags: content-editor, exm

When you are creating an email campaign on EXM, and go to the message tab, and select the body of message, then select one of the renderings, More, Edit component Properties, Add a rendering Parameter:

[image: EXM Message]

Save everything and go to the Content Editor, and find the item created under /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/, Presentation, Details, click the rendering you edited on EXM and notice that the rendering doesn't have any parameters:

[image: Content Editor Message]

The screenshots come from a clean installation of sitecore 9.1

Is this normal? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are checking the presentation details of the incorrect item. You should select the message root item under the newly created item. Also, make sure to select the final layout to check the additional parameters.
[image]

Comment: Woops, yeah that was it!
Thanks a lot!